# Sum Calculation for Tax

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

Can you please help me on Crystal Report, where I'm trying to create a formula.

Case:

I have 2 tables, Table1 has some columns (like ItemName, ItemPrice, TaxType, TaxRate).

Table2 has Items sold with columns (like ItemName, Qty, ItemPrice, ItemTotal).

I have also linked the column in crystal report for ItemName, so that they can fetch related data.

I am looking for a formula in crystal report that can sum up tax rate * item total where tax type= VAT and TaxType= GST

My formula structure will be like:

```
VATSum ({table1.taxrate}*{table2.totalamount}) where table1.taxtype= 'VAT'

GSTSum ({table1.taxrate}*{table2.totalamount}) where table1.taxtype= 'GST'
```

Please guide.

I would really appreciate any body's efforts to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Group Expert you will want to begin by creating a Group on the `{table1.taxtype}` field.  This will ensure all of your `VAT` and `GST` items sold are grouped together.  If you have other taxtype values than `VAT` and `GST` you will need to decide how to handle those taxtypes.  You use Select Expert to filter them out if they are not needed for the report, or do nothing and they will all appear within additional groups on the report by their taxtype values.

You will need to then create a formula field that can be used to calculate the tax for each item sold.  The name of this formula will be referenced by other formula fields in the report, so I will call this formula field `itemTax` in this example.  The formula for this field will be:

`{table1.taxrate}*{table2.totalamount};`

Place the `itemTax` formula field into the details section of the report.

From here you have 3 options on how to calculate the sum of `itemTax`.  You may insert a Summary Field, a Running Total Field, or another Formula Field.  Any of them will work for you, but I will continue with the Formula Field option.

Create another formula field and name it `totalTaxByGroup`.  The formula for this field will be:

`Sum({@itemTax}, {table1.taxtype});`

Then place this formula field in the Group Footer section of the taxtype group.

Comment: First of all, thanks to R. McMillan. Is there any way where groups does not show in the detail section? I just want to show total tax amount of GST and Vat in report footer seperately.

Comment: Or is there any formula which can sum (taxrate*totalAmount) where TaxType= 'GST'?

Comment: You can suppress any sections you don't want to display by using the Section Expert.  You can suppress both the Group Header and the Details sections and then the only displayed sections will be the Group Footer where the summary data is displayed.

Comment: Hi R. McMillan, I tried to suppress the group header and group footer section. This is supressing the summary (not showing in detail section which is good but it is giving me a total of only one group in report footer). My requirement is, it should show the summary of both the group like VAT and GST in the report footer section and no summary should be shown in report section.

Comment: If this doesn't seems feasible to you. Than i would like to go through a formula like Total Vat= ({itemtotal} *{taxrate})  where {taxtype} = VAT rather than going to group expert. And same goes for GST.

Comment: By suppressing the group header section and group footer section. Summary is only showing only for one tax type i. e. Vat. How to show summary for GST also?